# XCOde 4 how to rotate view in xib?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I can't rotate the view in xcode4 to landscape: the dropdown that says "orientation" (under "simulated metrics") is disabled.
Any help? Thx.

Answer (score 4):

[Changing Interface Builder Orientation in Xcode 4](http://egosystems.wordpress.com/2011/06/08/changing-interface-builder-orientation-in-xcode-4/)

Answer (score 2):

That is only enabled if you have the status bar visible on the view I believe.